# How to count list size of parent entity in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController and I have a problem to query count in parent attribute.

Assuming that following data model, 'Group', 'Category', 'Item'.
- Item : All items belong to ‘Category’
- Category : ‘Category’ may belong to a certain ‘Group’
- Group : 'Group' has zero to N 'Category'

And I want to search all items which does not have any groups in category. 
My codes are following :

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
...
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((category.groups.@count == 0) || category.categoryId == %@)", categoryId];
...
```

But, "category.groups.@count" does not work in here. (It works well out of NSFetchedRequest)
How can I solve this problem. Please help me;;

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A relationship can also be nil.

```
(((category.groups.@count == 0) || category.groups == nil) || category.categoryId == %@)
```

The resolution of the code inside of the predicate when you are running against a SQLite backend can be different than what you expect inside of Objective-C directly.  When you run into odd things like this it can be helpful to turn on sql debugging to see what the underlying sql is and adjust your predicates accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but the codes are crashed... "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'". By the way, how to turn on sql debugging ?

Comment: Does Item have to-one relationship with Category? You can turn on debug via reading the Apple docs and [my post over on PragProg](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/90/topics/4649).

Answer (score 0):

You open 2 brackets, and close only one:

```
...@"((category.groups.@count == 0) || category.categoryId == %@"...
```

Comment: Oops ! It's just my typing mistake. However this problem does not solved. Anyway thanks for your reply.